# can we use apache flink for real time pef/excel file generation?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Currently we have a system which generates (exports) an excel file of a webpage where we show lot's of numbers in UI grid. This system is designed using Java Programming Language. The Problem as the number if users are growing the service is slowing down. Below are the steps of high level working of the service.

- The user submits the request for file export
- The request is received by the excel generation service which does set of HTTP API calls and generates an excel file, which is uploaded to google cloud storage
- At the end the file is download by the user

So can we use **Apache Flink** for exporting excel files in parallel?

Comment: Can you specify which part of the service is taking most of your time? Is it the API calls or the one that generates the files.

Comment: @AnuragAnand It's the API calls which is taking time.

Answer (score 4):

While you probably could implement this with Apache Flink, I don't think it's a good fit for this application. I would suggest you look at an event-driven, serverless computing platform instead.

Comment: Is there any Framework for that, as I can not use managed solution such as AWS/GCP serverless computing platform?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that is better to use an event-driven architecture instead of using Flink. You can create two services, one service that handles the HTTP requests and insert them in a queue/log (this way you decouple the services and is easy to increase the throughput as other many advantages) and have another service capable to consume that events previously inserted and generate the excel files